# Strange Decryption Output

Tags: c++, encryption

I was just experimenting with encryption and decryption and made a function to encrypt, decrypt and write both to a file...

```
void encrypt(const std::string& r){

std::string new_r = "Encrypted:\n";
for(int i = 0; i < r.length(); i++)
{
    new_r += ~r[i];
}

wtofe("/home/programming/Desktop/latin.txt", new_r); // Writes it to a file
decrypt(new_r);
}

void decrypt(const std::string& r){

std::string new_r = "Decrypted:\n";
for(int i = 0; i < r.length(); i++)
{
    new_r += ~(r[i]);
}

wtofd("/home/programming/Desktop/latin.txt", new_r); //Writes it to a file
}
```

Writing to the file and encrypting worked. It also decrypted it but take a look at this strange output :

[image]

What I wrote as input was Davlog and as you can see it has been added to the end of the decryption. But why? What did I do wrong?

Comment: show wtofd function... also you are descripting new_r, which is the string "Encrypted:\n" + the encrypted string

Comment: the wtofd function is not the problem and it is just a fstream which writes to a file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

```
void encrypt(const std::string& r){
  std::string new_r;
  for(int i = 0; i < r.length(); i++)
  {
      new_r += ~r[i];
  }

  wtofe("/home/programming/Desktop/latin.txt", new_r); // Writes it to a file
  decrypt(new_r);
}

void decrypt(const std::string& r){

  std::string new_r;
  for(int i = 0; i < r.length(); i++)
  {
      new_r += ~(r[i]);
  }

  wtofd("/home/programming/Desktop/latin.txt", new_r); //Writes it to a file
}
```

In your original code you were writing `"Encrypted:[your encrypted msg]"` instead of just `"[your encrypted msg]"` to your file. So the decrypt step would decrypt the "Encrypted:" part as well as the original encrypted message.